# Unable to use Java StringBuilder. append () as a global variable

Tags: java, java-8, stringbuilder, java-17

A StringBuilder declaration as a global variable

```
public class Test {

    public static StringBuilder sb1=new StringBuilder("Hello");
    public static void main(String args[]){}
}
```

I'm using Intellij IDE. After declaration if I try to use

```
public class Test {

    public static StringBuilder sb1=new StringBuilder("Hello");
    sb1.append(" world!");
    public static void main(String args[]){}
}
```

IDE suggests. append() is not available. Appending inside a method or at declaration level it works. Whereas appending after declaration is not working

```
public class Test {

    public static StringBuilder sb1=new StringBuilder("Hello").append(" World!");
    public static void main(String args[]){}
}
```

Just wanted to know why it is not working after declaration at global level. Can anyone help me with this

Comment: Please read a basic Java tutorial. Statements need to go inside methods or initialisers.

Comment: Because Java doesn't let you put code there in general.

Comment: You could place the statement into an initializer block, i.e. `static { sb1.append(" world!"); }`, to be executed after the initialization of the `sb1` variable. But why? What’s the purpose of the obsolete string concatenation? And, by the way, don’t use the legacy array syntax. A string array variable should be declared as `String[] arg`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you should have a public classes with inherited methods and variables. You can use the StringBuilder constructor in your main method, in which the code execution occurs and print the result.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        
        StringBuilder sb1=new StringBuilder("Hello").append(" World!");
        System.out.println(sb1);
    }
}
```

Or you can implement your StringBuilder in a separate method (in this case: `build()`) and execute this method in your main method and print the returned value inside the `System.out.println()` function. The function build() (you can insert any name you want), returns a `StringBuilder` Object to your main method.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        
        System.out.println(build());
    }
    
    public static StringBuilder build(){
        
        StringBuilder sb1=new StringBuilder("Hello").append(" World!");
        return sb1;
    } }
```

Third option: You use the StringBuilder constructor in a static block:

```
public class Test {
    
    static {
        StringBuilder sb1=new StringBuilder("Hello").append(" World!");
        System.out.println(sb1);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
    }
}
```

https://www.javatpoint.com/java-main-method